# Why is a variable in a lambda function not recognized

Tags: python, lambda

I am sorry for the vague description, but I have the simple question why this code is working:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'city': ['London', 'New York', 'Berlin', 'Seoul', 'Paris', 'Tokyo', 'Bangkok', 'Las Vegas', 'Cape Town'], 'continent': ['Europe', 'America', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'America', 'Africa']})

df.groupby('continent').agg(lambda x: print(x))
8    Cape Town
Name: city, dtype: object
1     New York
7    Las Vegas
Name: city, dtype: object
3      Seoul
5      Tokyo
6    Bangkok
Name: city, dtype: object
0    London
2    Berlin
4     Paris
Name: city, dtype: object
Out[372]: 
           city
continent      
Africa     None
America    None
Asia       None
Europe     None
```

And this code is giving the error that x is not defined (while x is used in the previous code as well):

```
df.groupby('continent').agg(lambda x: print(i) for i in x)
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-373-7d68f6ea91a2>", line 1, in <module>
    df.groupby('continent').agg(lambda x: print(i) for i in x)

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: I don't understand what you expect the non-working version to do, nor why/if you're confused about the working version. Did you try reading the documentation? You don't need to loop over the rows because the *point* of `.agg` is that it loops over the rows *for you*, in the same way that `.groupby` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(i) for i in x` syntax can be used only as part of a *list comprehension* expression.

Try:

```
df.groupby('continent').agg(lambda x: [print(i) for i in x])
```